# Different colours of geom_line above and below a specific value

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I have the following dataframe that I would like to plot. I was wondering if it is possible to color portions of the lines connecting my outcome variable(stackOne$y) in a different color, depending on whether it is less than a certain value or not. For example, I would like portions of the lines falling below 2.2 to be red in color.

```
set.seed(123)
stackOne = data.frame(id = rep(c(1, 2, 3), each = 3),
                     y = rnorm(9, 2, 1),
                     x = rep(c(1, 2, 3), 3))

ggplot(stackOne, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line(aes(group = id))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have at least a couple of options here. The first is quite simple, general (in that it's not limited to straight-line segments) and precise, but uses base `plot` rather than `ggplot`. The second uses `ggplot`, but is slightly more complicated, and colour transition will not be 100% precise (but near enough, as long as you specify an appropriate resolution... read on).

**base:**

If you're willing to use `base` plotting functions rather than `ggplot`, you could clip the plotting region to above the threshold (2.2), then plot the segments in your preferred colour, and subsequently clip to the region below the threshold, and plot again in red. While the first clip is strictly unnecessary, it prevents overplotting different colours, which can look a bit dud.

```
threshold <- 2.2
set.seed(123)
stackOne=data.frame(id=rep(c(1,2,3),each=3),
                y=rnorm(9,2,1),
                x=rep(c(1,2,3),3))
# create a second df to hold segment data
d <- stackOne 
d$y2 <- c(d$y[-1], NA)
d$x2 <- c(d$x[-1], NA) 
d <- d[-findInterval(unique(d$id), d$id), ] # remove last row for each group

plot(stackOne[, 3:2], pch=20)
# clip to region above the threshold
clip(min(stackOne$x), max(stackOne$x), threshold, max(stackOne$y))
segments(d$x, d$y, d$x2, d$y2, lwd=2)
# clip to region below the threshold
clip(min(stackOne$x), max(stackOne$x), min(stackOne$y), threshold)
segments(d$x, d$y, d$x2, d$y2, lwd=2, col='red')
points(stackOne[, 3:2], pch=20) # plot points again so they lie over lines
```

[image: base package, changing line colours]

**ggplot:**

If you want or need to use `ggplot`, you can consider the following...

One solution is to use `geom_line(aes(group=id, color = y < 2.2))`, however this will assign colours based on the y-value of the point at the beginning of each segment. I believe you want to have the colour change not just at the nodes, but wherever a line crosses your given threshold of 2.2. I'm not all that familiar with ggplot, but one way to achieve this is to make a higher-resolution version of your data by creating new points along the lines that connect your existing points, and then use the `color = y < 2.2` argument to achieve the desired effect.

For example:

```
threshold <- 2.2 # set colour-transition threshold
yres <- 0.01 # y-resolution (accuracy of colour change location)

d <- stackOne # for code simplification
# new cols for point coordinates of line end
d$y2 <- c(d$y[-1], NA)
d$x2 <- c(d$x[-1], NA) 
d <- d[-findInterval(unique(d$id), d$id), ] # remove last row for each group
# new high-resolution y coordinates between each pair within each group
y.new <- apply(d, 1, function(x) {
  seq(x['y'], x['y2'], yres*sign(x['y2'] - x['y']))
})
d$len <- sapply(y.new, length) # length of each series of points
# new high-resolution x coordinates corresponding with new y-coords
x.new <- apply(d, 1, function(x) {
  seq(x['x'], x['x2'], length.out=x['len'])
})
id <- rep(seq_along(y.new), d$len) # new group id vector
y.new <- unlist(y.new)
x.new <- unlist(x.new)
d.new <- data.frame(id=id, x=x.new, y=y.new)

p <- ggplot(d.new, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=d.new$id, color=d.new$y < threshold))+
  geom_point(data=stackOne)+
  scale_color_discrete(sprintf('Below %s', threshold))
p
```

[image: conditional line colour - ggplot]

There may well be a way to do this through ggplot functions, but in the meantime I hope this helps. I couldn't work out how to draw a `ggplotGrob` into a clipped `viewport` (rather it seems to just scale the plot). If you want colour to be conditional on some x-value threshold instead, this would obviously need some tweaking.

Comment: Thank you. I had heard that the melt function could also be useful for such problems, but this sounds like a great solution.

Comment: I've edited the solution to include a method using base plots together with `clip`.

Comment: `ggplotGrob` uses inner viewports itself, which is why clipping wouldn't work.

Comment: @baptiste: thanks for that.. I had found [your discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/ggplot2/i2QaFsqdv8Y) with Hadley, and wasn't sure whether you'd found a solution (I assume you hadn't). Cheers for clearing that up.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, @jbaums! I've taken the liberty to update it to dplyr and the newer fancy stuff R can do these days. To anyone interested, you can check the code here: http://opiateforthemass.es/articles/dwd-daten/

Answer (score 7):

Encouraged by people in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66817508/how-make-line-red-when-the-value-is-below-zero-and-green-when-above/66817776) to a newer but related question, I'll also share a easier to use approximation to the problem here.

Instead of interpolating the correct values exactly, one can use `ggforce::geom_link2()` to interpolate lines and use `after_stat()` to assign the correct colours after interpolation. If you want more precision you can increase the `n` of that function.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
#> Warning: package 'ggforce' was built under R version 4.0.3

set.seed(123)
stackOne = data.frame(id = rep(c(1, 2, 3), each = 3),
                      y = rnorm(9, 2, 1),
                      x = rep(c(1, 2, 3), 3))

ggplot(stackOne, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_link2(
    aes(group = id,
        colour = after_stat(y < 2.2))
  ) +
  scale_colour_manual(
    values = c("black", "red")
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this really easy solution! It works for most of my data, but in a few cases, it also draws a straight line between the first and last values of my dataset. Any thoughts on what could be causing that?

Comment: Ah! It appears that values have to be sorted from low to high along the x-axis first.