# Recolouring geom_line() by treatment factor level for cross-over study

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, line, levels

I have looked at [How to obtain multiple colours for geom_line conditional on a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543402/how-to-obtain-multiple-colours-for-geom-line-conditional-on-a-specific-value)

and I am wondering/hoping that I can get some help with a related problem i.e. how to change the colour of `geom_line()` depending on a the level of a third factor. So I have a cross-over design for a treatment. Each individual (Specified as IDNUm) has two treatments in random order (Treat: levels = "Q", "S") and results of outcomes measured at three consecutive visits  (Visit: levels = "B","T1","T2"). So I want to plot an outcome (Result) at each of the time points connected by a line which changes colour depending on what treatment they have had in that interval (i.e. B(aseline) to T1, and T1 to T2).

```
ggplot(s,aes(x=Visit,y=Result,group=IDNum,colour=Treat))+geom_line()
```

gives me a plot where the line colour is defined by the first treatment only and doesn't change for the second interval

Comment: It's hard for anyone to say anything without more details - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: would be useful to have some sample data