# Use geom_line() to colour by a positive or negative number

Tags: r, ggplot2

Sorry if this is a duplicate question but other answers I have tried have not resulted in my desired plot.

I would like to colour code this graph based upon whether the value is positive or negative which I have termed the "phase".

Where the geom_line() hits just above or below 0 I would like it to colour either "positive" or "negative" - I thought the following would work but it doesn't seem to. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong? Thanks.

[image: original plot]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffJQf.png)

#### Data

```
structure(list(Date = c(1876, 1877, 1878, 1879, 1880, 1881), 
    value = c(4.95, -10.0416666666667, 2.95, 12.85, 7.8, -4.76666666666667
    ), phase = structure(c(3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("negative", 
    "neutral", "positive"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7ffb06817ce0>)
```

#### Code

```
## create a column to determine if the phase is negative, positive or neutral i.e. 0

dd_avg$phase<-factor(sign(dd_avg$value), (-1):1, c('negative', 'neutral', 'positive'))
dd_avg
 

## plot it up

ggplot(data=dd_avg, aes(x=Date, y=value, group=Date, colour=phase))+
  geom_line()
```

[image: plot2]

Comment: What goes wrong? Please can you include a figure of your output

Comment: Hi Richard, if I use the code geom_line() nothing will plot and I get the error geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
If I put geom_line(group=1) etc it produces the second plot where it creates two separate groups and connects the first and last point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By manually assigning colours, you're triggering the automatic grouping that ggplot2 does, which will just draw seperate lines for positive and negative. However, even if you override the grouping, you're still faced with the problem that a line segment can only have a single colour and lines that cross the 0-line will likely give problems.

The usual solution to such problems is to interpolate the data to specify exact cross-over points. However, this is annoying to do. Instead, we can use `ggforce::geom_link2()` that already interpolates and use `after_stat()` to apply colouring after interpolation. If you need your cross-over points to be exact, you might want to interpolate yourself.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

df <- data.frame(
  x = seq(as.Date("1890-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-01"), by = "1 year"),
  y = rnorm(131)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_link2(aes(colour = after_stat(ifelse(y > 0, "positve", "negative"))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

There are similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9543402/11374827) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66817508/11374827) where I've suggested the same solution.

Comment: Great thank you, that was exactly what I was after